# Using system symbol table from VxWorks RTP

Tags: vxworks

I have an existing project, originally implemented as a Vxworks 5.5 style kernel module.

This project creates many tasks that act as a "host" to run external code. We do something like this:

```
void loadAndRun(char* file, char* function)
{
    //load the module
    int fd = open (file, O_RDONLY,0644);
    loadModule(fdx, LOAD_ALL_SYMBOLS);

    SYM_TYPE type;
    FUNCPTR func;
    symFindByName(sysSymTbl, &function , (char**) &func, &type);

    while (true)
    { 
        func();
    }   
}
```

This all works a dream, however, the functions that get called are non-reentrant, with global data all over the place etc. We have a new requirement to be able to run multiple instances of these external modules, and my obvious first thought is to use vxworks RTP to provide memory isolation.

However, no matter what I try, I cannot persuade my new RTP project to compile and link.

```
error: 'sysSymTbl' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

If I add the correct include:

```
#include <sysSymTbl.h>
```

I get:

```
 error: sysSymTbl.h: No such file or directory
```

and if i just define it extern:

```
 extern SYMTAB_ID    sysSymTbl;
```

i get:

```
  error: undefined reference to `sysSymTbl'
```

I havent even begun to start trying to stitch in the actual module load code, at the moment I just want to get the symbol lookup working.

So, is the system symbol table accessible from VxWorks RTP applications? Can moduleLoad be used?

**EDIT**
It appears that what I am trying to do is covered by the Application Programmers Guide in the section on Plugins (section 4.9 for V6.8) (thanks @nos), which is to use dlopen() etc. Like this:

```
 void * hdl=  dlopen("pathname",RTLD_NOW);
 FUNCPTR func = dlsym(hdl,"FunctionName");
 func();
```

However, i still end up in linker-hell, even when i specify -Xbind-lazy -non-static to the compiler.

```
undefined reference to `_rtld_dlopen'
undefined reference to `_rtld_dlsym'
```

Comment: Well, the kernel symbol table is not afaik. available in RTP apps. In RTP apps you can create shared libraries though, and use dlopen()/dlsym(), which may allow you to do similar things. You do have symLib.h available, though RTP apps will use header files in the `usr/h/` directory, so that is a different header than what kernel modules would use.

Comment: @nos Hmm.... That could work. I dont particularly want to modify the code we are calling, but this would just be a case of changing the build properties I guess.

Comment: Although i now get undefined reference to `_rtld_dlopen' :-(

Comment: You'll need to link to libdl for that iirc. linker flag -ldl , if you're using a gcc toolchain

Comment: The fix was actually to use -Xbind-lazy -non-static as _linker_ options, not _compiler_ options as the documentation said. So i know have something that links, just got to get the plugin loading now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that the documentation says to specify -Xbind-lazy and -non-static as **compiler** options. However, these should actually be added to the **linker** options.

libc.so.1 for the appropriate build target is then required on the target to satisfy the run-time link requirements.