# undefined reference when calling code in downloadable kernel module

Tags: c, linker, vxworks

Following on from a previous question [Using system symbol table from VxWorks RTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812080/using-system-symbol-table-from-vxworks-rtp).

I am porting an existing vxworks kernel module to an RTP, however, much of the actual functionality is still embedded in other "downloadable" kernel modules. These are loaded using loadModule (as part of the startup process), and so should be in the system symbol table at the point my RTP runs.]

However, I cannot get my RTP to build, getting errors from the linker regarding undefined references.

How can I persuade the linker to ignore references to these functions? I am passing the `-Xbind-lazy -non-static`  options to the linker.

As an example, the kernel module (built as database.out) might contain code such as

`void writeDatabaseValue(int , char*);`

and my RTP application code calls it in the usual way

```
void main (int)
{
     //do some stuff
     writeDatabaseValue(0,"foo");  //Linker error here
     taskDelay(100);  //but no linker error here
}
```

I have tried adding `database.out` to the link line using `-l:database.out`, which resolves the reference to writeDatabaseValue, however I then get into dependency hell, as the linker then tries to resolve all of `database.out`s references, including all of the standard vxworks api calls.

EDIT: Just for extra complication, some of the kernel module code I want to call is in the same module that actually spawned my RTP......

Answer (score 2):

You are really trying to shoehorn one environment into a totally different one and are experiencing the pain inherent in this approach.  I don't believe you will be able to get the linker to ignore the references.

Might be better to use symbolic links (available from within the Workbench environment) to source files and use those in a RTP project.

Or create dynamic libraries based on the DKMs (again, use symbolic links) and link those against your RTP.

As an example, let's say you have the following Workbench workspace:
DKM1
DKM2
RTP

Based on the question, you are attempting to link DKM1 & 2's object files in the RTP and are experiencing pain.

A better approach is to add a project link to the source files in DKM1 & DKM2 and have them compiled in the RTP.  Because it is a link (instead of a copy) then changing the file in the DKM (to fix a bug for example) would also change it in the RTP.

In the RTP project, do a "New > Directory".  Select the "advanced" button and check the "link to existing directory" then select the "DKM1" directory.
All the source file in the DKM1 will now be part of the RTP.  Do the same with DKM2.

When you compile the RTP project, these new files should also be compiled.

Comment: Do you an example on how to do this?